# Existance of piecewise continious function if laplace transformation is given.

Tags: numerical-methods, laplace-transform, piecewise-continuity, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

How to confirm if there exists a piecewise continuous function $f(t)$ whose Laplace transform $F(s)$ is given? I know the existence theorem for the existence of Laplace transform but don't know how to use it?
Say if $F(s)=e^{s^{2}+1}$, how can I confirm if there exist a piecewise continuous function $f(t)$ corresponding to the given $F(s)$?

Could you please explain it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer**

I plotted numerical integrals for $t\in[-4,4]$
$$f(t)={\mathcal {L}}^{-1}\{e^{s^2+1}\}(t)={\frac {1}{2\pi i}}\int _{ -i \infty}^{i\infty}e^{st}e^{s^2+1}\,ds$$
There should exist an inverse

[image]

Comment: how can I calculate the inverse Laplace transform? I am not being able to solve this integral. Also what does it mean by plotting numerical integral? Could you tell please!

Comment: @UjjawalM. The inverse is the integral I wrote in my comment (not an answer). I don't know if it has a nice closed form. I couldn't find it anywhere. Plotting numerical integral is much easier. I computed an approximation of the integral for several points in $[-4,4]$ and plotted the results. BTW, where does this problem come from? Why did you tag "numerical-methods"?

Comment: I think inverse Laplace transformation of exp(s^2+1)would be a Gaussian distribution and the function which I have got is same as you have plotted. I have calculated the Laplace transformation of Gaussian distribution and got exp(as^2-bs) type function in frequency domain, which gave me clue about it's inverse must be a Gaussian distribution. I have tagged numerical methods by mistake, actually I am studying mathematical methods. Thanks!